# Cannot Call Data in text editor in C Programming

Tags: c, function, file-handling

I write code in c programming to write data in a text file and displayed, but when I calling the function the data doesn't displayed in a text editor.

I want to see the data when I calling in a text editor.

```
    void payment_list()
    {
        struct flat d;
        FILE *Ptr_file;

        Ptr_file = fopen("payment.txt", "w");

        if (Ptr_file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to Open the File\n");
            return;
        }

        printf("\nFlate No\tName Surname\tPayment\t\tDate\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");

        while (fread(&d, sizeof(struct flat), 1, Ptr_file) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%.2f\t\t%s\n", d.no, d.name, d.surname, d.payment, d.date);
        }

        fclose(Ptr_file);
    }
```

Comment: You can start another program/process (in your case a text editor) using the "system" function. "system" is in the standard C library and should be available if you include "stdlib.h". If you are writing a Windows API program, you could instead use the "CreateProcess" function.

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr.  When `fopen` fails, the error message should include the system generated reason for the failure.  For example: `FILE *Ptr_file;
char *name = "payment.txt"; Ptr_file = fopen(name, "w"); if (Ptr_file == NULL) { perror(name); exit(1); }`

Comment: We don't know what your input file is, we don't know what `struct flat` is.  Does the program work outside your editor?  Maybe call`feof() / `ferror()` to figure out why your loop terminated?

Comment: Note that you're doing `fopen` with `"w"` which is open for _writing_ and truncate the file (_no_ read access). Then, you're trying to _read_ it with `fread`. Use `"r"` to [just] read from it. Or, to open it for _update_ (open for reading _and_ writing _without_ truncating it), use `"r+"` Doing `man fopen` will explain all this.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what your interaction with a text editor might be. Also you mention that you want to write into a file but your code only reads from the file. Please try to rephrase your question to provide more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  If my answer didn't fix it, then it's a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. `fopen("payment.txt", "w");` will truncate your file.  Use "r" instead if you want to read from it.
2. If you are on Windows then you also want to open the file in binary mode.  So "bw" when writing to it (if you want to truncate it), and "br" when reading from it.

On this here is a minimal working program (on Linux which doesn't have a concept of binary mode for files):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
#define BINARY_MODE "b"
#else
#define BINARY_MODE ""
#endif
#define PAYMENT "payment.txt"

struct flat {
    int no;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    float payment;
    char *date;
};

void payment_list() {
    FILE *f = fopen(PAYMENT, BINARY_MODE "r");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Unable to Open the File\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nFlate No\tName Surname\tPayment\t\tDate\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");
    struct flat d;
    while (fread(&d, sizeof d, 1, f) == 1)
        printf("%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%.2f\t\t%s\n", d.no, d.name, d.surname, d.payment, d.date);
    fclose(f);
}

void payment_list_write(size_t n, struct flat payments[n]) {
    FILE *f = fopen(PAYMENT, BINARY_MODE "w");
    if(!f) {
        printf("Unable to open file for writing\n");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(payments, sizeof *payments, n, f);
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    payment_list_write(
        2,
        (struct flat []) {
            {1, "John", "Smith", 1.23, "2023-04-07"},
            {2, "Jane", "Doe", -2.34, "2023-04-08"}
        }
    );
    payment_list();
}
```

and here is the output:

```
Flate No        Name Surname    Payment         Date
--------------------------------------------------------
1               John Smith              1.23            2023-04-07
2               Jane Doe                -2.34           2023-04-08
```

Comment: I  edit it to: fopen("payment.txt", "r"), but still, there is a problem I can't read the data into a text editor for example visual code

Comment: Please update your question with the information and things we wanted you to try in the comments.  To me, most important, is to figure out if your program works on the command line so we know if it's your program (now fixed) or also  your editor.